# RESOLVED: How to repair GRUB...after installing GRUB Customizer

Tags: grub2, busybox, customizer

**Ubuntu 20.04.2**

CRASHED. Wasn't doing anything unusual and my computer crashed. I believe it was caused by the 2TB WD hard drive as it's refurbished (but also a Heavy Duty model). Happens once every 5-6 months or so. Usually I just reboot and all is fine. This time...

On reboot, things got squirrely and seemed to be related to GRUB. I have recently install that Grub Customizer app that I'd installed BEFORE I knew how bad it was so I really didn't change much with it. I did try to put in a nice background on the GRUB screen but that didn't work at all, that's when I read up on it and found out what a disaster it can be, and that's all I've used it for. My reading though, tells me that it's fine as long as nothing happens, that it can't really be removed, so best to leave it alone. I've also read that it screws up your boot big time if you DO have a problem.

With that background in mind...after the crash I was just getting Busybox 'initramfs' on reboot so I tried booting to all the usual 'Boot restore' apps I have on USB stick or CD and nothing helped. After those programs designed to repair a boot problem with Ubuntu ran, they didn't display any error messages. Even so, the computer wouldn't boot and got worse and worse until I have NOTHING but a black screen with a single line message in white type at the top of the screen:

"/dev/sda1: clean, 48xxxx/120xxxxx files, 206xxxxxx/936xxxxxxx blocks". The x=numbers.

And that's all. I've left it on all night and those numbers barely change.

Anyone have any tricks to restoring GRUB after Grub Customizer ruins it?

Note that I can use BIOS to boot to the drive I'm using now and then access everything on the drive that won't boot as it's the secondary drive. My Win10 is on a separate drive that I unplugged so not involved with this. Then I have a USB backup drive that has the old GRUB on it.

So here's my questions: 1) Is this just a GRUB problem/issue?  2) Can I use the backup GRUB file(s) to overwrite the bad? If so, what's the procedure using Term? 3) Is there some procedure I can use to restore boot if I Live Boot to the 20.04 DVD that I have?

Thanks!

Edit: I found the root cause of my OS crash...when plugging in a USB device, I accidentally schmooshed a couple pins in the USB connector, because the plastic guide had broken off and fallen out. Later, one of those pins touched ground. Caused the crash and the resultant 'no boot' issue. Replaced that bad USB socket an hour ago but it's still not booting to the drive. All my files are still there, just won't get past the black screen, so I've been trying Rescue but can't get it to attach to the wifi adapter and the SSID I want to use.

**RESOLVED AROUND MAY 5TH**

**Basically gave up:** What I did was try every trick in the book I could find online to get the drive to boot, trying to stay with recent dates with my attempts and could ***not*** find ANY method or trick that would make my crashed HDD bootable. So I just went ahead and copied the home directory over to a different HDD (I have several); then reinstalled Ubuntu 20.04.1 on it. And that worked great. Drive is now safely stored as a bootable backup.

What worries me is that this current drive I'm using now *also* has that Grub Customizer app on it. But I've never used it on this drive, and I know it can't be removed. Really sad that an App that's available all over the net and has known issues that can crash a system and make it unbootable is still available without a warning! How can that be!? I know the FOSS warning about free apps but AFTER it's a known problem why is it still out there untagged as being a problem?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can do a total reinstall of grub. Grub customizer not only updates some standard settings files, but replaces all the scripts with its vesions "proxy" files. A full reinstall will replace to and make standard grub default, but any changes you have made will be lost. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I have run that Boot-Repair from a USB stick, from CD, and just an hour ago after booting to Ubuntu 20.04 Live DVD. AND I downloaded and upgraded it before running it. And like all the other times I'd run Boot-repair, there was no error message, it behaved like it worked, but it changed nothing.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the PPA comment, '2nd option'? I'll try it again with the live DVD. And try to find that.

Comment: If you go to the Boot-Repair link, it has two ways to get Boot-Repair. One is an bootable ISO, which may not be quite as updated as the ppa. You use the Ubuntu live installer and add the ppa. Then it downloads the newest copy of Boot-Repair into your live installer. If system seems to be correct, it will not suggest any fixes, but you can go into the advanced mode and choose to totally reinstall grub & latest kernel. shows advanced mode screens: https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: Okay, I'll try that again. The 2 times I tried already, there's a bug in boot-repair where it gets confused by all the USB ports and gets all pissy and insists there's no USB Wifi adapter. No way to advance so have to reboot the computer. I haven't tried it directly after a downloaded upgrade like occurs when I use the live CD yet though. FYI, I have a new2me Gigibyte mobo. AMD 6 core.

Comment: Made no difference at all. Booted to the 20.04 Live CD, opened term, updated the boot-repair ppa, ran it from Term, found the 'restore' line which was checked by default, (so was the other choice), and followed onscreen outputs from the program and it all went well. Came back and told me it was fixed and that I could reboot. Did that and it's exactly the same. One line of info shown when booting to the HDD and won't proceed past that. For my system, with GRUB Customizer installed, Boot-repair DOES NOT WORK. Apparently.

Comment: I missed your link earlier but now that I checked it out, I see it's from 2012 so not sure it's up to date enough to be of much help. I did do the 'Advanced Options' thing this last time.  There is only one drive so it would default there. The only thing I didn't do was 'Purge Grub...' option. I'll try that and see if it makes any difference. I'm beginning to wonder if it's a GRUB problem at all. What else could cause a Ubuntu HDD to hang at the 'files' and 'blocks' line during boot? Thanks!

Comment: Can you get into the grub menu when you boot? If you're getting that /dev/sda1 screen, you got past grub. sounds more like a video driver issue.

Comment: I can now, since I ticked that checkbox for 'Pruge Grub...' option. I now actually have a grub displayed on boot. I only checked it once, made my choice and it went directly to the single line page, so not fixed. No splash pages for Ubuntu in between. There were several options listed, like the boot-repair program (which has a couple grammar and spelling mistakes making me think it was written offshore) copied the grub from this HDD which I'd left connected. Fun.

Comment: Checked it again just now and all the grub choices were copied from the working drive for some reason. I was thinking it was going to create a generic grub, guess not. Might have if I'd unplugged the other drive it copied it from. Oh, and I misspoke. It does show a splash screen after I make a grub choice, there's a delay, then the single line pops up and it goes no further.

Comment: Have you tried the recovery boot or the second line in grub or line in the sub-menu? What video card/chip do you have?

Comment: I am going to try it again using the LiveCD, the ppa, and choose Purge but this time I'll unplug this HDD so it has to come up with a generic grub. I'd like to see what that looks like in this situation. I'm wondering if Linus wrote Boot-repair. Dunno how good his English is. Probably better than mine.

Comment: Again, you're making it past grub. Your desktop just isn't starting.

Comment: You are correct. Before the Purge, it wouldn't show any grub, now it does, so progress. I'm using an expansion card for video...the Diamond Radeon HD5450. I'm going to go purge again now see what it does.

Comment: Well, that didn't work. Now have a black screen with <grub_rescue> on it. Hah! So that tells me that the grub repair routine needs some external disk space as a scratch pad? Why it couldn't use some of the 1TB of empty space on the 2TB drive I'm trying to fix, I have no idea.

Comment: I'm going to do a full backup of the drive before I go any further and that'll take hours (938GB) so I'm not going to be working on this for the rest of the day. In answer to your question, "Have you tried the recovery boot or the second line in grub or line in the sub-menu?" Yes, several times. As I mentioned, the boot-repair that came on CD and USB stick, when I choose the 2nd choice on the screen, it can't find the wifi even though it finds it fine when I chose the 1st option. Shows an error message about not finding a bunch of USB ports (?), and then locks up the computer.

Comment: Or perhaps I don't understand the question...

Comment: Back to a boot on the broken drive that shows grub, and I can go to recovery mode, but choosing any option doesn't seem to do much of anything. fsck returns quickly and gives the e2fsck: Cannot start message, if I try to umount, I'm told it's busy? Network flashes a message on the screen but I don't know what it's telling me...if doesn't go to a network config page so I can start my Wifi (no router available, just my phone's hotspot). So I'm stuck now at the Restore and still not booting to the GUI when I try, just that single line.

Comment: Please don't put RESEOVED, SOLVED, FIXED etc. in the question title, and the solution to your question in the question itself. This is a question answer site. You are most welcome to answer your own question by clicking the **Answer my own question** button and putting the solution there.  Then you accept your answer as the correct one by putting the green check mark next to your answer. That will help others. However in this particular case, I am voting to close this question as the problem can't be reproduced or was only relevant for a specific period of time.