# How to start wifi in Recovery - 20.04

Tags: networking, wireless, data-recovery

Computer boots, goes to grub but ends up stalled on the "/dev/sda1: Clean" page and won't advance. If I choose recovery mode, there are some commands I could use IF I have wifi. But if I click on 'Network', something flashes on the screen but goes away immediately. So fast that I can't read it. I can go to root, but how do I install wifi network there? None of the google links make much sense or they're too old, or they're many many pages long.

Does anyone have a simple method of getting wifi setup and running in Recovery mode so I can download and install as suggested by recovery?

Comment: What has happened that the OS needs to clean the file system? What caused you to reboot before this message?

Comment: This happened: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1331631/how-to-repair-grub-after-installing-grub-customizer?noredirect=1#comment2270985_1331631

Comment: I found the root cause of my OS crash...when plugging in a USB device, I accidentally schmooshed a couple pins in the USB connector. Later, one of those pins touched ground. Caused the crash and the resultant 'no boot' issue. Replaced that bad USB socket an hour ago but it's still not booting to the drive. All my files are still there, just won't get past the black screen, so I've been trying Rescue but can't get it to attach to the wifi adapter and the SSID I want to use.

Comment: Found that I can use $nmcli dev wifi connect [essid name] password [type here w/o brackets]; that allows me to attache to wifi. After doing that, I get the 'can't resolve host' error. I give up.